# Detect string with multiple conditions and mutate column in r

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have Lookup_DF which contains dictionary to refer strings and Raw_file which has combination of strings, Lookup_DF is having Types to populate in Result data frame based on Items in raw files.

```
Item1=c("Banana","Toamto","Potato","Palak")
Item2=c("","Orange","Onion","Mango")
Type1=c("Fruit","Vegetable","Vegetable","Leaves")
Type2=c("","Fruit","Vegetable","Fruit")

DF1=data.frame(Item1,Item2,Type1,Type2)

Items=c("Onion,Potato,Ginger","Tomato","Banana","Palak,Mango","Onion,Capsicum","Orange,Sweet_potato")

Raw_file=data.frame(Items)

Result_Type1=c("Vegetable","Vegetable","Fruit","Leaves","","")
Result_Type2=c("Vegetable","","","Fruit","Vegetable","Fruit")
Result=data.frame(Items,Result_Type1,Result_Type2)
```

My Output data frame would look like Result.
I tried something with str_detect in case statement but not able to get it. Can someone help me out on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do a join between these two tables (similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64460207/3460670)).

First would put `DF1` in long format. For `Raw_file`, use `separate_rows` to have a single item in each row before the join.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF1_long <- DF1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = c(".value", "number"), 
               names_pattern = "(\\w+)(\\d+)$")

Raw_file %>%
  mutate(value = Items) %>%
  separate_rows(value) %>%
  inner_join(DF1_long, by = c("value" = "Item")) %>%
  group_by(Items) %>%
  distinct(Items, number, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Items, 
              names_from = number, 
              values_from = Type, 
              names_prefix = "Result_Type")
```

**Output**

```
  Items               Result_Type2 Result_Type1
  <chr>               <chr>        <chr>       
1 Onion,Potato,Ginger Vegetable    Vegetable   
2 Tomato              NA           Vegetable   
3 Banana              NA           Fruit       
4 Palak,Mango         Fruit        Leaves      
5 Onion,Capsicum      Vegetable    NA          
6 Orange,Sweet_potato Fruit        NA
```